# Blender does not use GPU while rendering a project in the Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, gpu

I hope someone can help me, as this can help boost my rendering times.

I created a new video sequence project and double checked in the settings - my GPU is recognized, screenshot:

[image]

When I render the video though and check the gpu temperature, it is pretty normal (60-65 degrees). When I play games, it usually peaks up to 80-100 degrees, so I would expect something similar when rendering with Blender.

Does Blender use the GPU when using a video sequencer template? How can I double check if Blender is using my gpu?

I also have ffmpeg with h264_nvenc enabled (I can measure the difference in the console, up to 100% more speed), but cannot see this listed in the rendering options:

[image]

Comment: I changed from Eevee to Cycles (I don't know if it makes any changes), though I use video editing. Maybe this would use the gpu instead?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the VSE is not even multi-threaded, let alone GPU accelerated.

Comment: I see 200% CPU in top, which is maybe 2 cores. Not sure.

Comment: The VSE is an old and outdated tool. Use a modern video editing app, like DaVinci Resolve free, or openshot. Don't waste your time with blender. Blender is great for 3D, not for video editing.